# Run a Azure DevOps job with different user

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have one Azure DevOps build pipeline which deploy few alerts on Azure Cloud with ARM template. I want to deploy alerts on different azure cloud accounts and prior to deploy the alerts I need to list few things as those information is required to deploy the code.
my question is, to get details from another account I need to execute Azure DevOps pipeline with different user which has additional privileges. When I trigger a job it use my credentials so how can I switch user to execute that privileged user to deploy the alerts.  Is there any way where I can configure that user in pipeline?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Just a remind of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you can use REST API to run your builds. You can ask other users to provide you with a Personal Access Token, and then you can use this Personal Access Token as credentials to run the REST API.
Here is the document about queue a build: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1 .

Here is a sample I tested in postman:
[image]
[image]

You only need to change the Personal Access Token here to use a different account to run builds.
You can also run this REST API in a PowerShell task. Here is a sample:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization name}/{project name}/_apis/pipelines/{build id}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview.1"
$contentType = "application/json"
$user="user"
$token="$(PAT)"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$body= @'
{
"definition":
{
"id":172
}
}
'@
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType $contentType -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
```

You can change the PAT in the variables.